# How to fetch data in JSX and load on page

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-router

I'm trying to use ASP.NET core with React and JSX. So far I'm able to fetch the data, but when I run FetchCustomer.tsx it is empty.

This is the controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ICTask1.Models;

namespace ICTask1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DBContext _context;

        public CustomersController(DBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Customers
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomer()
        {
            return await _context.Customer.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Customers/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customer.FindAsync(id);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return customer;
        }

        // PUT: api/Customers/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer(int id, Customer customer)
        {
            if (id != customer.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CustomerExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Customers
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> PostCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            _context.Customer.Add(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetCustomer", new { id = customer.ID }, customer);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Customers/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> DeleteCustomer(int id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customer.FindAsync(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Customer.Remove(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return customer;
        }

        private bool CustomerExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Customer.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my FetchCustomer.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

interface FetchCustomerData {
    customerList: CustomerData[];
    loading: boolean;
}

export class FetchCustomer extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any, any>, FetchCustomerData> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { customerList: [], loading: true };
        fetch('api/Customers')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<CustomerData[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ customerList: data, loading: true });
            });

        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.renderCustomerTable(this.state.customerList);

        return <div>
            <p>
                <Link to="api/Customer">Create New</Link>
            </p>
            {contents}
        </div>;
    }

    //Delete
    private handleDelete(id: number) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?" + id))
            return;
        else {
            fetch('api/Customers/5/' + id, {
                method: 'delete'
            }).then(data => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        customerList: this.state.customerList.filter((rec) => {
                            return (rec.customerId != id);
                        })
                    });
            });
        }
    }

    private handleEdit(id: number) {
        this.props.history.push('api/Customers' + id);
    }

    private renderCustomerTable(customerList: CustomerData[]) {

        return <table className='table'>
            <p>This is table</p>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    customerList.map(cust =>
                        <tr key={cust.customerId}>
                        <td></td>
                            <td>{cust.name}</td>
                            <td>{cust.address}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleEdit(cust.customerId)}>Edit</a>  |
                            <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleDelete(cust.customerId)}>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>;

    }

}

export class CustomerData {
    customerId: number = 0;
    name: string = "";
    address: string = "";
}
```

The API in the customer controller is working fine here is the output. I have used `api/Customers` in FetchCustomer.

When I run the project there isn't any error page. It is loading fine, but data is not visible:

[image]

When I run FetchCustomer I get this:

[image]

Comment: you are setting `loading` as `true` when the data loads, it should `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're several issues in your code:

1. As @Agney comments above, you need change the loading to false when loaded. Otherwise, the table itself won't be rendered.
2. Your server returns a list of customer which has a property of **`Id`**, while your TypeScript client expects a property of **`customerId`**. You need to map the array of `{id, name, address}` to an array of `{customId, name, address}`
3. You're nesting a `<p>` element within the `<table/>`, which is not correct.
4. The `handleEdit(id)` function pushes the URL like `this.props.history.push('api/Customers' + id);`. It's likely you should change it to `('api/Customers/'+ id);`
5. Also, you have five `<th>`s in `<thead>` while having four `<td>`s in each row.

To fix the above issues, you could change the code as below:

```js
export class FetchCustomer extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any, any>, FetchCustomerData> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { customerList: [], loading: true };
        fetch('api/Customers')
            .then(response => response.json())
            // Map each {id} to {customId}
            .then(data => data.map((d: any) => { return { ...d, customerId : d.id };}) )
            .then((data: CustomerData[]) => {
                // Change {loading} to false
                this.setState({ customerList: data, loading: false});
            });
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : this.renderCustomerTable(this.state.customerList);

        return <div>
            <p>
                <Link to="api/Customer">Create New</Link>
            </p>
            {contents}
        </div>;
    }

    // Delete
    private handleDelete(id: number) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure?" + id))
            return;
        else {
            fetch('api/Customers/5/' + id, {
                method: 'delete'
            }).then(data => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        customerList: this.state.customerList.filter((rec) => {
                            return (rec.customerId != id);
                        })
                    });
            });
        }
    }

    private handleEdit(id: number) {
        this.props.history.push('api/Customers/' + id);
    }

    private renderCustomerTable(customerList: CustomerData[]) {

        return <div>
        <p>This is table</p>
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th >ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    customerList.map(cust =>
                        <tr key={cust.customerId}>
                            <td>{cust.customerId}</td>
                            <td>{cust.name}</td>
                            <td>{cust.address}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleEdit(cust.customerId)}>Edit</a>  |
                                <a className="action" onClick={(id) => this.handleDelete(cust.customerId)}>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual data of the promise will be under response.data. Try the below code.

```
this.setState({ customerList: data.data, loading: true });
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"giving the below code"*?